# Safari web notifications empty logging response

Tags: php, safari, web-notifications

i'm literally going to lose my mind here. I'm trying to check the log messages sent to my /v1/log folder but the response is empty.

So what i'm doing

i'm printing the messages using print_r($_REQUEST, true) located in /v1/log/index.php

Tried to move all end points to the same file

```
window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission(
    'https://sub.domain/safari_pushes?action=',
    'web.sub.domain',   
    {},
    checkRemotePermission      
);
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks guys.